Persist sessions with Spring security after restart without database/cache
I use Spring Boot 3.2.5 with MVC and Spring Security.
Currently, users have to login again if the application has restarted.
As far as I read Tomcat has the ability to persist sessions by setting
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
in the application.properties.
For testing, I made a simple app (see below).
However, it is not working. If I additionally set
server.servlet.session.store-dir=sessions
then the folder sessions is created after I stop the application, but it is empty. The user still has to log in again.
What am I doing wrong, or is it not possible?
application.properties:
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
server.servlet.session.store-dir=sessions

AppController:
@Controller
public class AppController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "logged in";
    }
}

AppConfiguration:
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        var admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
    }
}


The setting is working correctly. The problem was, that the application was stopped with a SIGKILL signal by the IDE. For the context to gracefully stop, SIGTERM is needed. With SIGTERM, the sessions are correctly persisted to the disk and everything is working.

how does it behave if a graceful shutdown is set for the project? At application properties.  I wonder to know if it will be helpful for this case.

@catch23  Do you mean server.shutdown=graceful? If yes, it did not make any difference.

for correct work, do you stop the app from the terminal?

@catch23 I use IntelliJ IDEA. When running the application, there are two options to stop the application: 1) the red square symbol (SIGKILL) and 2) a symbol showing a red exit (SIGTERM). However, when running the application in debug mode, the SIGTERM-symbol does not show (I don't know why exactly). On the production server, the application is running as a service controlled by systemctl. When calling systemctl stop on the service, then SIGTERM is send by default.

Most information for the session is stored in Redis or Hazelcast. Don't think it is possible to store sessions without some external storage.
In your case, a much better idea would be to store information with a JDBC session.
Add appropriate dependency:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

Also, update application.properties:
spring:
  session:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
      table-name: SPRING_SESSION

It should create 2 databases: spring_session and spring_session_attributes:

When you log in to the app you will new entry stored in DB.
Additional resource: Spring Session

Thank you for the answer. According to the documentation, the settings I provided above should work. That is, theoretically it should be possible make use of tomcats built-in session storage mechanism (sessions are stored in a temporary directory on the hard drive). JDBC, unfortunately, is not an option for us.

Tomcat stores sessions anyway. By default it could be stored to /tmp. Try to set it directly with server.tomcat.basedir.

Setting server.tomcat.basedir did not help either

a few things you should keep in mind before rushing into implementation

let's say you are able to persist the sessions on disk, depending on your deployment platform you might loose that disk too
if you'll need to horizontally scale your service - such solution might limit you to a sticky session approach (since you'll have session per service)
if you wish to avoid centralized session cache - you can consider using jwt tokens instead of session. you can read more about session vs jwt token


Thank you for the response. 1. sessions would only be stored temporarily between application restarts. There is no need to persist sessions (critical data is stored in a database with backup cycles etc.) 2. our service is horizontally scaled, it works fine. 3. due to some restrictions and requirements we can not rely on JWT tokens. I am looking for a specific answer for the option described above and documented in the Spring docs.

in that case you may want to debug TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureSession, which should later invoke configurePersistSession this will probably shed light on the missing piece you're looking for
